# Need to make a Class A which can be instaceated only from G

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

i Have a class G which will make instance of the classes Like A B C D each classes are in different packages,

While making instance of the A B C D each has different factory methods because arguments are different.

and no other classes can call the factory method of these A B C D classes.

Is any way to do this?

Comment: I don't think so, not if they're in different packages. If they were in the same package you might use package level access.

Comment: These kind of things are exactly what `package`s are for.

Comment: Please describe WHAT you are trying to do (that is, why do you think you need this type of class structure.  The solution may well be in your object model, rather that in class implemenation

Comment: I want manage the objects of (ABCD) only from manager which is G, No one can access the factory method of the ABCD. if they want object of ABCD they have to ask G, where G have knowledge of creating the objects on ABCD

Answer (score 2):

Lets Assume that you have

**CLASS B**

```
package com.b;

import com.g.ClassG;

public class ClassB {
    private ClassB(int arg1,String arg2){

    }

    public static ClassB getInstance(Object object) throws Exception {
        if(object instanceof ClassG) {
            return new ClassB(1, "Shree");
        }else {
         throw new Exception("instance creation is Only supported for ClassG");
        }
    }
}
```

**CLASS A**

```
package com.a;


import com.g.ClassG;

public class ClassA {
    private ClassA(int arg1){

    }

    public static ClassA getInstance(Object object) throws Exception {
        if(object instanceof ClassG) {
            return new ClassA(1);
        }else {
            throw new Exception("instance creation is Only supported for ClassG ");
        }
    }

}
```

Then If you write your class G as below

**CLASS G**
    package com.g;

```
import com.a.ClassA;
import com.b.ClassB;

public final class ClassG {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    ClassG gObject = new ClassG();
    ClassA aObject  = getClassAInstance(gObject);
    ClassB bObject  = getClassBInstance(gObject);

}

    private static ClassB getClassBInstance(ClassG gObject) throws Exception {
        return ClassB.getInstance(gObject);
    }

    private static ClassA getClassAInstance(ClassG gObject) throws Exception {
        return ClassA.getInstance(gObject);
    }

}
```

I think above solution would be sufficient for you .

1. restriction of instance creation is put in factory method
2. Class G is final hence There would not be any way to create ClassA and ClassB instances except Class G

Let me know your feedback on this

Comment: According to this whoever have object G can make call to the getinstance.. I need to make only from the G

Comment: As per your commentes "I want manage the objects of (ABCD) only from manager which is G, No one can access the factory method of the ABCD. if they want object of ABCD they have to ask G, where G have knowledge of creating the objects on ABCD"   .Any Other class wants to create Instances of A/B/C Should ask G for it . and only way of asking G would be through G's instance. I dont know whats missing here. Say you want to call **getClassAInstance** method from Class G . you will need to create object and call it . Is there any other way to call ?

Comment: One more thing is you can also declare private constructor in ClassG .With this no other class can instantiate ClassG. So with this only ClassG can now work on Instance of A,B,C

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to make these classes only have package-private constructors, and only the factories be public.

Packages are the only real way in Java to specify access permissions for related classes.

You'd have to put them all in the same package, though.

One hacky workaround could be to have your factory methods take a `G` instance as a parameter (and check that it is not null), and make it impossible to create `G` instances from any other place then `G` itself.

```
 public class G {

    private G (){}   // no one can make G instances

    public static A makeA(){
       return A.publicFactoryThatNeedsG( new G(), theRealParameters);
    }

 }
```

Very ugly.

In particular, ties A,B,C,D to G.